# Disconnecting Android emularor in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm using **eclipse Kepler**, and **ADT** bundle for **android development** and when I run an android project the **emulator** began to disconnect. I tried again after restarting the Eclipse IED and even I reboot my machine. But it's stay the same. Can someone help me with some useful advice. Thank you!!!

Comment: do u get any message/error???

Comment: Try to restart your ADB from ddms.

Comment: open "DOS Command Prompt" in yout Android SDK-> platform-tools folder and enter these commands : `adb kill-server` then `adb devices`

Comment: logcat shows "emulator disconnecting".and console shows `[2013-12-02 11:41:05 - AndroidV4Virtusel] New emulator found: emulator-5556
[2013-12-02 11:41:05 - AndroidV4Virtusel] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-12-02 11:42:23 - AndroidV4Virtusel] emulator-5556 disconnected! Cancelling 'xont.virtusel.v4.controller.AndroidVenturaActivity activity launch'!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The communication with the emulator or your Android device might have problems. This communication is handled by the Android Debug Bridge (adb).

Eclipse allows you to reset the adb in case this causes problems. Select therefore the DDMS perspective via Window → Open Perspective → Other... → DDMS

To restart the adb, select the "Reset adb" in the Device View.

for more info : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDevelopmentProblems/article.html

Comment: I reset the ADB. But same thing happens over and over again. some times my program run for a short time and then emulator go offline. Could it be something wrong with my IDE or ADT plugin.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. Your link also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal or Command Prompt of what OS you use , then use the following command

```
adb kill-server
```

Then type

```
adb start-server
```

finally

```
adb devices
```

You should see the attached devices and eclipse will find it. Make sure adb path has been added to your system path before you apply these commands.

Answer (score 0):

I also face with the same issue, Samantha Withanage. When I run the project on the emulator, and face with the same issue, I re-run the project (without closing/restarting anything viz. Emulator, Eclipse or the machine). Then it works fine.
Try this scenario from your end as well. Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: tried, but had the same. shows this in console when stopping execution.`AndroidV4Virtusel] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'xont.virtusel.v4.controller.AndroidVenturaActivity activity launch'!`.